# why there is separate checksum in TCP and IP headers?

Tags: networking

What is the need for having checksum at various layers ? For eg, there is a checksum in TCP layer and again in IP layer and also Ethernet layer has it.
Is not it sufficient to have checksum at one layer ?

Comment: "transport layer", "network layer" and "data-link layer" are the actual names btw.

Answer (score 21):

All three layers are needed, for multiple reasons:

- IP does not always run over ethernet (imagine IP over RS-232 serial, something every Cisco and Unix box can do)
- IP does not checksum the data
- TCP packets can be reassembled incorrectly from IP packets and fragments that each have perfect checksums
- Even if reassembled correctly, software or other errors could be introduced in the layers between IP and TCP
- Even if all software functions correctly, and TCP/IP is over ethernet, the limited size of the checksums can be accidently correct (and *will* be at some point, given enough packets) in the face of persistent errors, so having more than one checksum is helpful.
- Every time a new header is introduced there is more to checksum, and the new layer can't see the header bits of the layer below.

Comment: The RFC says, the TCP checksum covers the entire segment, whereas the IP checksum covers only the IP headers from errors.

Comment: +1 Very informative, and I think the last reason is the most convincing one.

Answer (score 10):

Ethernet checksum is a hop to hop checksum - meaning that it is recomputed everytime the Ethernet header fields change. TCP/UDP checksum is a end-to-end checksum meaning it is computed by the sender and verified by the receiver. TCP/UDP checksums cover the entire segment. IP checksum covers only the header. Ethernet CRC covers the entire frame.

Answer (score 2):

The designers of IPv6 decided it's not necessary at all those layers and removed it in favor of checksums at other layers (such as those you mentioned).